# Is my CUDA kernel really runs on device or is being mistekenly executed by host in emulation?

Tags: debugging, cuda, printf, gpu

I just got my GPU-enabled video card and started playing with CUDA. Just to get my head straight with blocks and threads I wrote a simple kernel that just stores its identifiers to the shared memory that I later copy back to host and print. But then I though, why not simply use `printf` inside the kernel function? I have tried that even though I believed that it was impossible. Here is what my attempt looked like:

```
__global__ void
printThreadXInfo (int *data)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    data[i] = i;
    printf ("%d\n", i);
}
```

.. but all of the sudden I saw the output in console. Then I searched developer's manual and found `printf` mentioned in the section about device emulation. It was said that device emulation provides a benefit of running a host-specific code in the kernel, like calling `printf`.

I don't really need to call `printf`. But now I am a little bit confused. I have two assumption. First is that NVidia developers implemented some specific `printf` on device that somehow transparently for the developer accesses calling process and executed standard `printf` function, and takes care of memory copying etc. That sounds a bit crazy. Another assumption is that the code I have compiled somehow runs in emulation rather than on a real device. But that doesn't sound right either because I simply measured a performance of adding two numbers on 1 million elements array and CUDA kernel manages to do it like 200 faster than I can do on a CPU. Or maybe it runs in emulation when it detects some host-specific code? If that is true, why am I not issued a warning then?

Please help me sort it out. I am using NVidia GeForce GTX 560 Ti on Linux (Intel Xeon, 1 CPU with 4 physical cores, 8 GB of RAM, if that matters). Here is my `nvcc` version:

```
$ /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_May_12_11:09:45_PDT_2011
Cuda compilation tools, release 4.0, V0.2.1221
```

And here is how I compile my code:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_21,compute_20\" -m64 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -isystem /opt/boost_1_46_1/include -isystem /usr/local/cuda/include -I../include --compiler-bindir "/usr/local/cuda/bin" -O3 -DNDEBUG -o build_linux_release/ThreadIdxTest.cu.o -c ThreadIdxTest.cu

/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_21,compute_20\" -m64 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -isystem /opt/boost_1_46_1/include -isystem /usr/local/cuda/include -I../include --compiler-bindir "/usr/local/cuda/bin" -O3 -DNDEBUG --generate-dependencies ThreadIdxTest.cu | sed -e "s;ThreadIdxTest.o;build_linux_release/ThreadIdxTest.cu.o;g" > build_linux_release/ThreadIdxTest.d

g++ -pipe -m64 -ftemplate-depth-1024 -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -pthread -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -fno-tree-pre -falign-loops -Wuninitialized -Wstrict-aliasing -ftree-vectorize -ftree-loop-linear -funroll-loops -fsched-interblock -march=native -mtune=native -g0 -O3 -ffor-scope -fuse-cxa-atexit -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wreorder -Wcast-align -Winit-self -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-parameter -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -isystem /opt/boost_1_46_1/include -isystem /usr/local/cuda/include -I../include -L/opt/boost_1_46_1/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lgtest -lgtest_main build_linux_release/ThreadIdxTest.cu.o ../src/build_linux_release/libspartan.a -o build_linux_release/ThreadIdxTest
```

... and by the way, both host code and kernel code is mixed in one source file with `.cu` extension (maybe I am not supposed to do that, but I saw this style in SDK examples).

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of CUDA ?3.1?, they no longer do *any* device emulation.  Printf's are now supported in the kernel.

Comment: every once in a long while, my memory works..  [Here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/cudatoolkit_release_notes_linux.txt) the original note in 3.1 that they facilitate printf() directly from the kernel *as long as you're using a Fermi architecture card*.  (Which the 560 is!)

Comment: It explains it all, perfect. Thank you very much!