# Why did device code can access host variable in cuda like this?

Tags: c++, cuda

In the code below, I have use the thrust library, what I don't understand is in the device

code I can access `v`, which I think is in host memory, because I direct give it the value

`4` in the constructor.

```
struct op{
    float v;
    op(float iv):v(iv){}
    __device__
    void operator()(float v2)
    {
         printf("%f\n", v+v2);
    }
};
int main()
{
    device_vector<float> data(4,1);
    for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), op(4));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code above is `5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0`.

So, can you give some hints about this behavior? I have searched through the official

manual, but didn't get any information about this behavior.

---

Sorry for my express, just like Ben Voigt said, my problem is "`what I don't understand is in the device code I can access v, which I think is in host memory`"

Comment: What do you expect the output of your code should be and why? It isn't clear what you want to know from your question as it is written

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: He doesn't appear to be asking what the computation IS, but where it is performed, CPU or GPU, and in what memory the data is stored.

Comment: Seems somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6560313/103167

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: He specifically said "what I don't understand is in the device code I can access `v`, which I think is in host memory"

Comment: @BenVoigt Hopefully they'll clarify what exactly they're looking for.

Comment: Yes, @BenVoigt is right. Sorry for my express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is not in host memory, at least not if the functor object is instantiated in device code. (And your struct, whose `()` operator only has a `__device__` decoration, would only "work" in device code.)

`iv` starts out in host memory, but the process of copying from `iv` (host) to `v` (device, at least if the `op` object is used in a thrust device operation) is handled by thrust prior to computation of the `for_each` function.

The copying of the `op()` initialization parameter (4, in your case) is really no different than what needs to happen with the `1` parameter here:

```
device_vector<float> data(4,1);
                            ^
```

That `1` parameter exists in *host code*.  However the thrust constructor for `device_vector` initiates the necessary host->device memory copies (and/or kernel calls, depending on the specific thrust function) to initialize the `device_vector` storage, which exists *on the device*.

This is handled at runtime, not compile-time.  You can replace your `4` constant with a variable, and still get valid results, just as you could replace your 1 initializer for `device_vector` with a variable.

That is how I would explain it.  Probably talonmies or JaredHoberock (or others) can correct my terminology, but I think the gist is correct.

Comment: So, in this `for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), op(4));` function call, it must call a hidden `__global__` function and in this `__global__` function it instantiated a `op` from the parameter and now the newly instantiated `op` is in device memory. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Either a hidden `__global__` function or a hidden `cudaMemcpy` function, or both.  Run your thrust code with `nvprof`.  You will see all sorts of "hidden" stuff going on.

Comment: I think it's the parameter to the `op` constructor, and the `op::v` variable it assigns, that is the source of confusion, not necessarily the size of the `device_vector`.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the size of the `device_vector`.  The parameter I indicated is not the size parameter for the constructor.

Comment: I would go along with most of that, except the bit about the intialisation parameter being copied. It isn't the parameter which is copied, it is *the whole instance* which gets passed by value. It must do, since there would be a compilation error for the lack of a `__device__` constructor if instantiation of the object took place on the device. The contents of the host instance are passed by value as a kernel argument when the operation is performed (a "closure" in Thrust parlance).

Comment: The thrust source code is too complicate to read for me, can you give me some help about understand what did thrust do underground? @talonmies